On a definition of covering space in terms of fiber bundles
I'm currently taking a course in (smooth) fiber bundles. I am not very used to covering spaces, but I'm trying to understand them in the language of fiber bundles. I would like to know whether the definitions below are equivalent, so that I can formulate the idea of covering space in terms of fiber bundles.
The first definition is taken from Munkres's Topology, p. 336. I am adapting the language of topological spaces to that of smooth manifolds
Definition 1. [Evenly Covered, Munkres] Let $\pi \colon E \to M$ be a smooth surjective map. An open set $U \subseteq M$ is said to be evenly covered by $\pi$ if $\pi^{-1}(U)$ can be written as the union of disjoint open sets $V_{\alpha} \subseteq E$ such that, for each $\alpha$, $\pi\vert_{V_{\alpha}} \colon V_{\alpha} \to U$ is a diffeomorphism.
Definition 2. [Covering Space, Munkres] Let $\pi \colon E \to M$ be smooth and surjective. If for each $p \in M$ there is a neighborhood $U$ of $p$ that is evenly covered by $\pi$, then $\pi$ is said to be a covering map and $E$ is said to be a covering space of $M$.
Now there is my attempt at a definition in terms of fiber bundles.
Definition 3. [Covering Space, Mine] Let $\pi \colon E \to M$ be a fiber bundle over $M$ with typical fiber $F$. If $F$ is discrete, i.e., if $F$ is $0$-dimensional, then we say $\pi$ is a covering map and $E$ is a covering space for $M$.
Are definitions 2 and 3 equivalent?

Usually the concept of "covering space" is defined for topological spaces. In this more general context, a covering map is a continuous surjection $\pi : E \to M$ between topological spaces $E, M$ such that for each $p \in M$ there is an open neighborhood $U$ of $p$ that is evenly covered by $\pi$ which means that $\pi^{-1}(U)$ can be written as the union of disjoint open sets $V_{\alpha} \subseteq E$, where $\alpha$ belongs to an index set $F(p)$, such that, for each $\alpha \in F(p)$, $\pi\vert_{V_{\alpha}} \colon V_{\alpha} \to U$ is a homeomorphism.
You consider smooth covering maps between smooth manifolds in which case one requires that $\pi\vert_{V_{\alpha}} \colon V_{\alpha} \to U$ is a diffeomorphism.

If $F$ is discrete, i.e., if $F$ is $0$-dimensional, ...

This is correct for manifolds. There is also a concept of dimension for general topogical spaces, and there exist $0$-dimensional spaces which are not discrete. Therefore, for topological covering maps one must omit the i.e. part.
Anyway, Munkres's definition and your definition are equivalent if and only if $M$ is connected.

A fiber bundle with discrete fiber $F$ is obviously a covering map because each $p \in M$ has an open neighborhood $U$ of $p$ such that there exists a homeomorphism (diffeomorphism) $h : p^{-1}(U) \to U \times F$ with the property that $proj_U \circ h = \pi_{\pi^{-1}(U)}$, where $proj_U : U \times F \to U$ is the canonical projection. This implies that $p^{-1}(U)$ is the union of the disjoint open sets $V_\alpha = h^{-1}(U \times \{\alpha\})$ with $\alpha \in F$ and that $\pi\vert_{V_{\alpha}} \colon V_{\alpha} \to U$ is a homeomorphism (diffeomorphism).

An open neighborhood $U \subseteq M$ of $p$ being evenly covered means that there exists a homeomorphism (diffeomorphism) $h : p^{-1}(U) \to U \times F(p)$ such that $proj_U \circ h = \pi \vert_{\pi^{-1}(U)}$.

With Munkres's definition it is obvious that the cardinality of $F(p)$ is locally constant. Hence, if $M$ is connected, then the cardinality of $F(p)$ is constant and we can use the same index set $F$ for all $p \in M$. This means that for each $p \in M$ there is an open neighborhood $U$ such that there exists a homeomorphism (diffeomorphism) $h : p^{-1}(U) \to U \times F$ with the property that $proj_U \circ h = \pi \vert_{\pi^{-1}(U)}$. Thus $\pi$ is a fiber bundle with typical fiber $F$.

If $M$ is not connected, we can write $M = M_1 \cup M_2$ with non-empty disjoint open subsets $M_i \subseteq M$. Take discrete spaces $F_1, F_2$ with different cardinality. Then the obvious map $\pi: E = M_1 \times F_1 \cup M_2 \times F_2 \to M$ is a covering map, but no fiber bundle.



These aren't equivalent for a silly reason. If $M$ is disconnected, we can get a Munkres-covering-space over $M$ such that the fibers over different connected components have different cardinalities (say) and there is no fiber-bundle structure on such a morphism since all the fibers aren't homeomorphic to each other.
If we require the base to be connected, they are equivalent. A covering space in your sense gives rise to a covering space in Munkres' sense (let $U$ be small enough to trivialize the fiber bundle; then each component of $U \times F$ maps homeomorphically to $U$ since $F$ is discrete). Conversely, when the base is connected, then over $U$, the map looks like $\text{discrete set} \times U$ mapping homeomorphically to $U$ (this is the paragraph in Munkres right after yours). Since a Munkres-cover has to have the same cardinality for each fiber (this is exercise 3 in that section), we can define $F$ to be $f^{-1}(p)$ for any $p$ (with the discrete topology).

FWIW I'm not sure if Munkres definition is standard; I think yours is more pleasing. But I haven't thought enough about disconnected bases when it comes to covering space theory.
